# Recursive use of mathematical expectation

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> Given $x_0, y_0, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, define a random process as: On turn $i$, probability of success is $x_i/y_i$. On success, $x_{i+1} = x_i + \beta$, else, $x_{i+1} = x_i$. And $y_{i+1} = y_i + \beta$ regardless. What is $E[x_n]$ ?

Intuitively, I would like to say something like: $E[x_{i+1}]= E[x_i] + \frac{E[x_i]}{y_i}\beta = E[x_i]\frac{y_{i+1}}{y_i}$ and thus that $E[x_n] = x_0\frac{y_n}{y_0}$.

However, I don't know if it's justified to use expectation like this. My thinking why linearity of expectation doesn't apply from the start is that $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ are from different sample spaces.

Comment: The formula you suggest holds because the $y_i$s are actually deterministic. No idea what you mean by "$x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ are from different sample spaces." Of course, every $x_i$ is defined on the same probability space. Thus, assuming $x_0\leqslant y_0$, $E(x_n)=x_0(1+n\beta/y_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use $X_n$ instead of $x_n$, since capital letters are customary for random variables.

$X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$ are all random variables defined on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Though it is not specified, the implication in this problem is that $(X_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is a Markov chain. The probability measure $P$ is defined so that $$P(X_{n+1}=X_n+\beta|X_n)=\frac{X_n}{y_n}=1-P(X_{n+1}=X_n|X_n),$$ where $y_n=y_0+n\beta$. This uniquely determines the probability of $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ taking any finite sequence.

With the setup rigorously specified, every step you performed was correct. Perhaps a step which can be filled in would be
$$
E[X_{n+1}]=E[E[X_{n+1}|X_n]]=E[(X_n/y_n)\cdot (X_n+\beta)+(1-X_n/y_n)X_n]=\dots
$$

Comment: I think my problem was the definition and understanding of "sample space". I thought that, since the $X_i$s represented the outcomes at different stages, they weren't in the same space. However, is it true that the sample space is the set of sequences that may occur, and that the $X_i$s are functions from this common set, to the real line?

Comment: @Abel That's right! One way to think of it is that the sample space consists of sequences $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)$ of real numbers, and $X_i$ is the projection operator $X_i(\omega)=\omega_i$.